# PuTTY won't open after closing once

Tags: putty

I've used PuTTY a few times but this morning when I launched it I made a mistake in the Command Prompt where I added a # to my username so I closed it to re open but now I just hear a sound when clicking open like something is already running but there isn't anything there.

I've restarted my computer but still get the issue and can't find anything in task manager.

Any advice please?

Answer (score -1):

Ok so the LOAD aspect wasn't launching at the top of the .exe file so I manually typed in for the connection and it worked. The ping must have been to advise a required field was empty

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).